# VBA to return the RANGE identified in OFFSET formula

Tags: excel, vba, range, offset

I'm desperately chasing circular reference errors in a very large workbook.
One of the culprits could well be within one or more OFFSETs which I use extensively.
I'm trying to write a VBA script which will cycle through all cells in the workbook, to find cases where the active cell is included within a range returned by the OFFSET.
For example, the cell formula might be:

```
=OFFSET($J1098,,MATCH(E$1071,$K$1071:$BD$1071,0))
```

or perhaps:

```
=SUM(OFFSET($AA$7,MATCH($W129,$A$8:$A$121,0),1,1,4))
```

Is there a way in VBA to return the RANGE identified by the OFFSET?
In some cases, I use the OFFSET to identify a range to be summed or averaged, so the return could be a single cell reference, or a range.
Much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO. *Is there a way in VBA to return the RANGE identified by the OFFSET?* You have that info in the formula. itself. Treat it as a string an extract the ranges.

Comment: Sorry to tell you this, but "extensive use of Offset" is really bad design.  You best bet may well be to bite the bullet now, and redesign your workbook now to remove reliance on Indirect cell references (which includes functions INDIRECT and OFFSET)

Comment: `Worksheet.CircularReference` might be useful here - it will give you the first range containing a circular reference (which you'd need to resolve before find in the next...)